# Reset uefi boot menu

Tags: uefi, disk, restore

If i used efibootmgr to delete ubunt, hard disk, and dvdrom, there will not be any uefi boot devices, how can i repair it? I did not delete anything, just asking, what would be.

Answer (score 0):

A complete answer depends on the firmware in your MB.
Two suggestions are;

1. Look at your firmware options and see if there is an option to boot into an EFI shell.  If so boot into the shell and modify the contents of the NVRAM using the bcfg shell command.  The first option is to look at the contents of the NVRAM using bcfg boot dump which will display all NVRAM boot options.  You can the use other bcfg commands to add entries.  The bcfg commands can be found in the UEFI Shell Commands Manual. From memory it will be something like bcfg boot add ?????  where ???? is the path to a bootloader.  Be aware that this path must be able to be read by the EFI firmware and a valid bootloader must be present in this location. It is usually in the EFI Partition which is normally a GPT Fat formatted partition.  Once you create a valid NVRAM entry you cab boot into that OS and use the OS tools (like efibootmgr) to further modify the NVRAM values.
2. If there is no firmware option to boot into an EFI Shell then try to restore the efi firmware defaults (probably called the BIOS Defaults) in your systems MB firmware.  This should restore NVRAM entries for things like Optical Drive, HDD's, and USB devices.  You may have to ensure that there are valid UEFI bootloaders on the optical and USB drives.

If all else fails I recommend reading about UEFI booting on Rod Smith's excellent pages on the subject.  Google Rod Smith Refind as a starting point.

Comment: Just realised that you need the later version of the ecu shell to use the bcfg command.  Version 1 does not include this command.